# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Tags: python, svg, pythonanywhere

This should be simple so not sure why I am getting the error in the title. SVG created is fine as I have manually checked

```
code to generate svg
....

mod_svg = 'final1.svg'
tree.write(mod_svg)

import cairosvg
fileout = open('finaltree','w')
cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=mod_svg,write_to=fout)
fileout.close()
```

Im using python 2.7 on pythonanywhere in case it matters.

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drdavepier/mysite/flask_app.py", line 184, in <module>
    cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=mod_svg,write_to=fout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairosvg/__init__.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    surface_type.convert(*args, **kwargs))(_surface_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairosvg/surface/__init__.py", line 82, in convert
    tree = Tree(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairosvg/parser.py", line 270, in __init__
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(bytestring)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1674, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101299)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96481)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91772)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

opening lines of the relevant SVG

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Created with matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) --><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="432pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 576 432" width="576pt">
```

initialisation of tree:

```
filename = "/path/to/file.svg"
with open( filename, 'r') as infile:
    tree = etree.parse( infile )
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: i am guessing where you initialize your variable tree is where the fault is. The XML reader is probably expecting something like <sometag> and you have something else in place of it.

Comment: thanks, I have added more info

Comment: maybe print out your bytestring before making the call to see what the first character is?

Answer (score 0):

there's special chars in your text

```
def transference(value):
    value = value.replace("<","&lt;")
    value = value.replace(">", "&gt;")
    value = value.replace("&", "&amp;")
    value = value.replace(r'"', "&quot;")
    value = value.replace(r"'", "&apos;")
    value = value.replace("×", "&times;")
    value = value.replace("÷", "&divide;")
    return value
```